# How to configure Helios to add new devices

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, helios

I setup helios and postgres DB. Also used houston to test notifications. But What I was more expecting to have a ability to add my devices in DB using REST endpoints that helios offers. Either I do not understand what it does or I may be missing something completely.

1)I could never do something like localhost:5000/devices/?token or localhost:5000/push_notification/devices/?token

2) Also on github https://github.com/helios-framework/helios by Matt the admin wb UI shows compose button - I never saw that one as well.

3) If this is just a framework and doesnt have ability to add new device token for APNS how exactly we use this for testing notifications in my app on multiple devices?